# Get product URL from multistore in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, multistore

I need to get the product url link for a certain product in a prestashop multistore with different domains.

I know i can get product link with something like this:
getProductLink($id_product)

But this return the url from the main store, I need to be able to get the product link of an specific id_store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use getProductLink with parameters. The 6th parameter is id shop.
Use

```
$link = new Link();
$link->getProductLink(1, null, null, null, null, 'your_shop_id_here');
```

within php, or

```
{$link->getProductLink(1, null, null, null, null, 'your_shop_id_here')}
```

within smarty